# How to write the converse, contrapositive and negation of "Every planar graph can be colored with at most four colors"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I cant find a way to rewrite the statement into a conditional statement, which would make writing the converse and contrapositive easier.

I was thinking about writing it as "If every planar graph can be colored, then the planar graph can be colored with at most four colors."

The converse: "If a planar graph can be colored with at most four colors, then every planar graph can be colored."

For the contrapositive: "If a planar graph cannot be colored with at most four colors, then some planar graph cannot be colored."

For the negation: "There exists some planar graph that cannot be colored with at most four colors."

Comment: The original statement is equivalent to, "If $G$ is planar, then $G$ can be colored with four colors."

Comment: See [Contraposition etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)

Comment: @saulspatz I'm not sure I understand why those two statements are equivalent, what you're saying seems to be that every planar graph can be coloured with exactly four colours, and OP's statement seems to be saying that no planar graph can be coloured with more than 5 colours, or am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: @Carlyle I meant it to mean "at most four colors."

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{“Every planar graph can be colored with at most four colors”}$$

can be read as

$$\text{“For each planar graph, it can be colored with at most four colors”},$$

which can be read as

$$\text{“For each graph, if it is planar, then it can be colored with at most four colors”}.$$

As such:

- *converse*: Every graph that can be colored with at most four colors is
  planar.
- *contrapositive*: Every graph that cannot be colored with at most four
  colors is not planar.
- *negation*: There is some planar graph that cannot be colored with at most four colors.